# Ayuda con sentencia SQL para mostrar en mi SELECT que datos no existen

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Saludos chicos requiero ayuda con lo siguiente:

Tengo una tabla con muchos datos mas de 6000 datos y requiero hacer una consulta en phpmyadmin donde yo suministrare un paquete de datos a buscar y este me indique que datos de los que yo estoy buscando no existen.
**Lo que Tengo**
Con la estructura siguiente me da como resultado del bloque de datos suministrados los que estan ejemplo si estoy buscando 200 datos me doy cuenta que ya hay datos que existen porque me muestra como resultado un total de 180 es decir hay 20 que no existen, y requiero determinar cual de los seriales suministrados son los que no existen y no se como debo generar la sentencia SQL para ello.

```
SELECT serial FROM tarjetas WHERE serial IN ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'......)
```

**Tambien intente con**

```
SELECT serial, ISNULL(serial,'NO EXISTE') AS No_Existe.....
```

Pero me da error.
Vale acotar que entre los datos que estoy consultando muchos de ellos ya estan en la tabla, y yo requiero es saber cuales **no** están en la tabla.

**Un Ejemplo de lo que requiero**
Si tengo los datos:
`Serial       contenido
   a             aa
   b             aa
   c             aa
   x             aa
   y             aa
   z             aa`

Y mi consulta es buscar los seriales `('c','d','e','f')` me enliste que los seriales `d, e y f` son los que no existen porque el serial `c` si existe en mi tabla.

Comment: Si ya habia intentado pero me da error

Comment: que error te da?

Comment: Bueno no es un error como tal, me da como resultado 2000 y pico de resultados pero mi consulta es de 700 datos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar tu misma consulta pero cambiando el "`IN`" por el "`NOT IN`". Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT serial FROM tarjetas WHERE serial NOT IN (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)
```

Comment: Me temo que no esta preguntando eso. Quiere aquellos valores de los que suministra (a,b,c,d...) NO estan en la BBDD. Tu query devuelve los valores de BBDD que no son esos valores.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu paquete (seriales a filtrar) los obtienes con el **IN** y si solo necesitas los que no se encuentran en ese conjunto, sólo debes hacer uso de la palabra reservada **NOT** junto al **IN**, dela siguiente forma:

```
SELECT serial FROM tarjetas WHERE serial NOT IN ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h', ...)
```

**EDICION**

Debido a la aclaración, esto te podría ayudar.

```
-- Creas variable tabla
-- Creamos una variable tipo tabla para poder filtrar mediante join contra la tabla en base.
DECLARE @SERIALS TABLE(
    id_serial CHAR(20)
)

-- Insertas los datos
-- En esta parte cargas los datos que tienes en tu array, a la variable tipo tabla.
INSERT INTO @SERIALS
SELECT 'a';
INSERT INTO @SERIALS
SELECT 'b';

-- Reviso que la variable tabla esté cargada
SELECT*
FROM @SERIALS

-- Filtro los datos que no existen en la tabla de Tarjetas
SELECT*
FROM @SERIALS AS B
LEFT JOIN TARJETAS AS S  --  Join contra la tabla en base.
    ON  (B.id_serial = S.serial)
WHERE S.serial IS NULL; -- Condición.
```

Espero te ayude. De todas formas pido ayuda al foro en la parte de la carga de datos en la variable tipo tabla, ya que puede haber una forma más óptima y menos engorroza de realizarla. Saludos.

Comment: puedo pensar, que se deba a que la forma de exprasarlo debe ser como caracteres, es decir entre comillas simples cada uno de ellos, no lo hice así estimando que sea implícito. Ya lo corrijo.

Comment: Si lo estoy colocando entre comillas simples.. debo hacerlo sin las comillas simples, solo separados por la coma..??

Comment: primero, de que tipo es la columan serial?, si es un caracter, de ley los elemtnos a evaluar deben estar representados como caracteres también. Si serial es un numerico, no es necesario las comillas. Las comas, son solo separadores. De ser posible y si aún así no logras tener la solución, compartenos un ejemplo.

Comment: Serial es un VACHAR(50) por eso coloco las comillas simples, y en efecto he editado mi pregunta para tratar de graficar de mejor manera lo que necesito..!

Comment: Me temo que no esta preguntando eso. Quiere aquellos valores de los que suministra (a,b,c,d...) NO estan en la BBDD. Tu query devuelve los valores de BBDD que no son esos valores.

Comment: @JDev, claro parece tener más sentido así. Es correcto ello @Jose!?

Comment: Si  @Rostan correcto de hecho he editado mi pregunta, tratando de graficar de mejor manera mi interrogante y he colocado un pequeño ejemplo de lo que debería hacer mi consulta. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

No se si es la forma mas correcta pero creo que esto te valdría.

**(1)** Primero obtenemos aquellos que si estan con esta query (hasta aqui todo normal)

```
SELECT DISTINCT serial FROM tarjetas WHERE serial IN ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h')
```

**(2)** Ahora creamos una select con todos los valores

```
SELECT valor WHERE valor IN ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h')
```

Ahora construimos la query final. Basicamente lo que hacemos es decirle que me de todos los valores de la query **(2)** que no esten en la **(1)**

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT valor WHERE valor IN ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h')) TABLA_TEMP WHERE TABLA_TEMP.valor NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT serial FROM tarjetas WHERE serial IN ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h')).
```

Es bastante probable que se pueda mejorar pero no se me ocurre ahora.

Comment: Me da este error #1054 - La columna 'serial' en field list es desconocida

Comment: Serial esta en tu BBDD por lo que tiene que existir.